# Java EE with several frontends

Tags: rest, mobile, angularjs, java-ee-6

At the moment I´m working on a simple JSF+Java EE 6+EJB+JPA2 application. 
The whole stack really works well together and the development speed is high.

Now I like to add more "mobile" functionality to my app / architecture. Which means I will create several native mobile applications which are communicating with my Java EE 6 backend. For the creation of the native app I think Phonegap is a great option. But I´m not sure about the communication with the backend and the JS Framework on the client side.

Currently I think a REST-Facade on the server side would be a good idea which will be used from AngularJS on the client side.

Anyone ever tried this approach? 
Are there better ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a sound architectural idea, and like all good ideas, it's already been done :).

See [AngularJS + PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498432/angularjs-phonegap) for confirmation.

There's also a 'Hello World' implementation available on github: [phonegap-angularjs-bootstrap](https://github.com/kronosh/phonegap-angularjs-bootstrap)

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try the demo app immediately